# C# - Looping methods and putting delays inbetween them

Tags: c#, .net, windows, loops, methods

I have several methods that are declared in the Main method.

Although how could I put a loop in, so in this case OutputChanges() would loop around to FileChanges(). And is it possible to put an break / interval of say 10 seconds inbetween the loop?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            FileChanges();

            FolderChanges();

            OutputChanges();

        }
```

Comment: Not sure why someone would close this as "Not a real question".  It may be basic, but it is certainly a real question, and SO doesn't discriminate against questions that could be answered with a quick google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention how many times you want to loop...so I'll go with the infinite loop (using [`Thread.Sleep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) to halt execution for 10 seconds between iterations):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true)
    {
        FileChanges();
        FolderChanges();
        OutputChanges();

        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, you are a scholor amoung men

Answer (score 2):

[System.Threading.Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while( true )
    {
        FileChanges();
        FolderChanges();
        OutputChanges();
        Thread.Sleep( 10000 );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to put the pause after OutputChanges(); and only a single pause.

Comment: @Jamie: Well then he can move that line.  I don't see any specification in the question as to when the sleep should occur, just that it should do so for each iteration.  You may be right, but I would hope that the OP could change the example for his purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

  while(true)
  {
     FileChanges();
     FolderChanges();
     OutputChanges();
     Thread.Sleep(10000);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int counter=0;
    do{
        counter++;
        FileChanges();
        FolderChanges();
        OutputChanges();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }while(counter<10)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reworking this to use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) instead.  The timer can tick every 10 seconds, at which time you can do your operations.